# Generate inner class

Tags: java, annotation-processing

my annotation processor reads a class like this:

```
@Foo
public class Bar (){

}
```

Now I want to generate an inner class `Bar$MyGeneratedClass`  so that at the end I have a class `MyGeneratedClass` that to the compiler / jvm looks like this:

```
public class Bar (){

   // Generated by annotation processor
   public static class MyGeneratedClass () { ... }
}
```

Is this possible? I think so, I guess I just have to name the generated class `Bar$MyGeneratedClass` right?

Does anybody know how to generate such a inner class with java poet?

Comment: It sounds a little like aspect oriented programming (AOP)

Comment: Why do you want it to be an "inner class" Do you use some framework that distinguish between inner classes and normal classes?

Comment: @vikingsteve No, I want to do that at compile time

Comment: @hege_hegedus it don't have to be an "inner class". The only advantage would be that if I do some refactoring like renaming on the "outer class" the generated code will still work without having to recompile the whole project to run annotation processing again to generate the "inner class" for the renamed "outer class". Hence I thought it would by nice to have it the generated class as inner class

Comment: Ok, I think I understand now, but I am afraid of it is impossible. Refactoring is done on the source, I don't think the IDE will alter precompiled class files during renaming. But it's just my intuition.

Comment: My intuition tells me this is an XY problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use javapoet to create new classes. It's not possible modify existing class with javapoet.

Answer (score 0):

On jvm level there is no such things as inner classes.
So while compiling both classes (the inner and the outer) are transfomed to simulate that effect.

- The inner class gets a constructor parameter. With that parameter you need to pass in an instance of the outer class.
- As both class types can access private members package private accessors are created.

Especially the second transformation requires you to change the outer class.